# Python pandas why does my code changes column when I import a dataframe from a csv file and then use concat to merge the two dataframes together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I am trying to create a program in which every time I enter a data, it stores it into a dataframe and the dataframe is stored into a csv file. Now, this whole process is in a loop. When I keep on entering the data without importing the data from the csv file, it works fine and the two dataframes are joined together perfectly. Now when I call the csv file, the data shifts into a different column. For e.g., I create a series having 6 columns. It will create a dataframe using that series. Now, if I want to add another row, the whole thing is on a loop so it will create another dataframe from the series and concat the two dataframes together. After every loop, the dataframe is exported into a csv file and the csv file is updated every loop. Suppose I used the loop twice, and then imported the csv file, the data starts from 3rd row but it creates a 5th column and all the data from the 1st column of the csv file starts from the csv file such that I end up having 8 columns.

```
name=input("Please Enter the Employee's Name:")
age=int(input("Please Enter the Employee's Age:"))
gender=input("Please Enter the Employee's Gender:")
Loc=input("Please Enter the Employee's Location:")
Des=input("Please Enter the Employee's Designation:")
Sal=int(input("Please Enter the Employee's Salary:"))
l1=[name,age,gender,Loc,Des,Sal]
df=pd.DataFrame(l1,index=index1)
df_Employee=pd.concat([df_Employee,df.T],ignore_index=True)
```

This is the original code which works inside an if statement and the to_csv function is used after exiting from the if...elif...else statement. All of this works inside a loop. I did not face a problem in concatenating the two dataframes and they merge together as I want it to like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/503Gf.png)

```
df_Employee.to_csv("Employee Details.csv")
```

Now, when I import the csv file, it shifts the columns in the csv file to a different column altogether. Below is the code that I used:

```
df=pd.read_csv("Employee Details.csv",header=None)
df_Employee=pd.concat([df_Employee,df],ignore_index=True)
```

When I use the above codes after I have created the dataframe given in the above image, it gives me this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Fbf.png)

However, when I terminate the program with the data saved in the csv file and on starting a new run, if the first thing that I do is import the csv file, it imports it as I wish, but when I make the third entry while running the program, it ends up creating a different column for that entry like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2NoA.png)

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an empty dataframe with the column names and then append the row you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=index1)
df = df.append(l1)
```

Comment: I tried using the append () function but it doesn't work